# Python correct use of scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, lambda, scipy, minimize

I am trying to perform minimization of the following function:

```
def mvqr(P, y, x, c):
    s = 0
    for i in xrange(1, len(y)):
        summation =  numpy.linalg.norm(numpy.dot(numpy.linalg.inv(P), (y[i,:] - numpy.dot(beta, x[i,:])))) + numpy.dot(numpy.dot(c.T, linalg.inv(P)), (y[i,:] - numpy.dot(beta, x[i,:])))
        s = s + summation
    return s
```

this are the lines of the main file:

```
fun = lambda beta: mvqr(E, Y_x, X_x, v)
result = minimize(fun, beta0, method = 'BFGS')
```

beta is the unknown variable of the function `mvqr()` and `beta0` is the initial guess, a `(2,2)` array I have previously calculated.

I got an error:

`NameError: global name 'beta' is not defined`.

For who is wondering if the file of the function `mvqr()` has already been located in the directory of the python packages, the answer is: yes, it has.

I think the problem is with `beta` in the `mvqr()` function and the use of `lambda` function.

Any help?

**EDIT**

Thanks to pv. the code now compiles with no error but when perform minimization does not iterate since the output of the function `minimize` displays the message `'Optimization terminated successfully.'` but simply does not iterate and returns the initial guess.

```
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 1
    nfev: 6
hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     fun: 1.2471261924040662e+31
       x: array([  3.44860608e+13,  -4.10768809e-02,  -1.42222910e+15,
                  -1.22803296e+00])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I have also tried with `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs` but the result is pretty the same:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
Current function value: 937385449919245008057547138533569682802290504082509386481664.000000
            Iterations: 0
  Function evaluations: 6
  Gradient evaluations: 1
```

It could be that unfortunately `beta0` is a local minimum or however a stationary point as holds `jac == [0, 0, 0, 0]` and therefore the algorithm terminates, but it looks strange to me that the initial guess is the minimum of the function (even if a local one). Does anyone have idea of how to avoid it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a typo?: `result = minimize(fun, beta0, method = 'BFGS')` shoudl be `result = minimize(fun, beta, method = 'BFGS')` e.g. beta without the `0`?

Comment: @EdChum Actually `beta0` is the initial guess for `scipy.optimize.minimize`. Or `x0 = beta0` to be more precise. And as I told I have previously calculated it.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Aside: this isn't your issue, but your `mvqr` function probably doesn't do what you want -- it returns on the very first step of the loop, when `i == 1`, and so the loop doesn't really accomplish anything.

Comment: @ mgilson The traceback is quite a long one and has some data files loaded with `pandas`. My concern is that I am missing something in defining the unknown variable. Note that the `optimization` is `unconstrained` so I don't know what are all the possible values of `beta`, I only have the starting point `beta0`.

Comment: @ DSM Do you mean the fact that I chose to loop in `xrange(1,len(y))` instead of `xrange(len(y))`?

Comment: @ DSM I check the function actually I wrote 'sum(iter1 + iter1)' that is completely a mistake! I will check if now it works

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're defining beta to be a parameter to be passed to your lambda function, but then not using it explicitly in the lambda function body.

Comment: @ FuzzyDuck Really beta is used in the function `mvqr()` to run out some matrix multiplication. I mean that `beta` is actually the variable I need to find through the minimization and should be a `(2,2)` array.

Comment: But a lambda function definition looks e.g. like this: `add = lambda x, y: x+y`. I would expect to see `beta` on both sides of the definition. Perhaps like this: `fun = lambda beta: mvqr(*beta)`

Comment: @FuzzyDuck the matter is I have other arguments to pass to function `mvqr()` namely `E, y, x, v` and they are well known instead as I' ve already got them

Answer (score 2):

Change definition to `def mvqr(beta, P, y, x, c):` and do `fun = lambda beta: mvqr(beta.reshape(2,2), E, Y_x, X_x, v)` and `minimize(fun, beta0.ravel())` if you wish to optimize value of `beta` that is a 2x2 matrix.

After that, consider reading a Python tutorial, esp. on global and local variables.

Comment: I have tried your answer but it returns: `status: 0
  success: True
     njev: 1
     nfev: 6
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
      fun: 9.3738544991924501e+59
        x: array([  3.44860608e+13,  -4.10768809e-02,  -1.42222910e+15,
        -1.22803296e+00])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
      jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])`. So basically doesn't compute any iteration and returns the initial value.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if the inverse of the Hessian (`hess_inv`) is the identity matrix, and the Jacobian (`jac`) is zeros then the iteration will not go anywhere. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization

Comment: @FuzzyDuck exactly! I had study lots of optimization stuff instead and if `jack == 0` that is a stationary point and as the `hess` is semi-positive definite is a point of minimum as well. My guess is it could be a local minimum, but it seems a bit strange to me as is the starting point of the algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried other starting points?  Your function evaluates to rather a large number. Furthermore,  your array of `x` values seems to span a wide range of magnitudes. Makes me speculate that it might be something numerical.